# Does MessageDifferencer on proto messages handles map?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I have to check the differences between the two protobuf messages for my program(C++). I am trying [MessageDifferencer::Compare](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer#MessageDifferencer.Compare.details) and [MessageDifferencer::Equals](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer#MessageDifferencer.Equals.details) for this.

I have a `map` field inside the proto message, which as we know is not guaranteed to be ordered. So, I want to know what is the `MessageDifferencer` take on this? Is anyone out of `Compare` or `Equals` functions have something to handle this case?

I mean that if the map is not ordered, how we can be sure that all of the elements in the first message are compared to the right elements in the second message?

My message is something like:

```
message foo
{
    // some-fields
    map<string, int64> bar = 2;
    // more-fields
}
```

I am new to both C++ and protobuf, so any idea in the right direction will be helpful.

**UPDATES:**

Even if I am comparing the same message, it is showing *mismatch* and I can see in the *difference-report* that it is because the same field is not getting match against each other.

From the protobuf [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps):

```
Wire format ordering and map iteration ordering of map values is undefined, so you cannot rely on your map items being in a particular order.
```

Comment: The way I remember on the implementation level `Map<A,B>`  is just a repeated sequence of A and B.

Comment: @sehe more like an unordered sequence, from the documentation: `Map's interface is similar to std::unordered_map, except that Map is not designed to play well with exceptions.`